# Using export Name from "./Name in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to move a React app into Create-React-App but struggling to get some things to work and not really knowing what is and what isn't allowed (regarding customisation and adding extra modules) with Create-React-App.

Currently the CRA with the source from the React app is failing to compile at:

```
export App from "./App/App"
```

With error:

```
./src/containers/index.js
SyntaxError: /Volumes/Mexico/Workspace/create-react-app-test/myapp/src/containers/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled (1:8):

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from (https://git.io/vb4yH) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

I don't wish to eject from CRA and I don't believe I can change the Babel configuration so I am not sure what to do.

Is this syntax supported in CRA?  If so, what should I do to get it to work. If not, do I have to rewrite all the code?

react-scripts 2.1.8
node v11.14.0
npm 6.9.0

Thanks,
Ashley.

Comment: please check and add CRA version you installed

Comment: Note that create react app 3.0.0 has been released recently, you could try that to see if they fixed your issue

Comment: export App from "./App/App",why you have used export instead of import
because of that i think so its giving error

Comment: Thanks for quick comments.  
I thought CRA version was defined by react-scripts version, that I provided?
Yes, just noticed CRA 3 but didn't know if it had achieved production, will check.
This export worked with custom Webpack and evrything configuration previously.
I just need to know if I can use it with CRA or have to change all code etc.

Comment: create-react-app --version is 1.4.1

Comment: These are the [list](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features#supported-language-features) of features supported by CRA. The syntax you're trying to is not supported. Either eject and change babel config or find [ways](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/167) to modify the babel config without ejecting.

Comment: Update to CRA3 (just released on 22/4) but no fix. Thanks to @MaazSyedAdeeb for definitive answer.  This syntax is used extensively through the code but I don't wish to eject so will look for ways to modify the babel config unless that is really unrecommended. I know it's infinite but may be useful to have a list of things CRA doesn't support as well as what it does support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export App from "./App/App"` is not among supported [`export` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax) variations.

In order to be spec-compliant, it can be changed to:

```
export { default as App } from "./App/App"
```

Comment: But can I have multiple of these? 
I currently have:
export App from "./App/App"
export Home from "./Home/Home"
export About from "./About/About"
...

Comment: I updated the answer. You can have multiple named re-exports this way.

Answer (score 1):

These are the [list](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features#supported-language-features) of features supported by CRA. The syntax you're trying to is not supported. Either eject and change or find [ways](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/167) to modify the babel config.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
export {default as App} from './App/App';
export {default as About} from './About/About';
.
.
.
```